# Cannot convert error when assigning array to a range

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, runtime-error, google-sheets

Below is my code and on the last line of code I get a "Cannot convert error". *To clarify the line: `sheet.getRange` throws the error.*

That is all the error says; nothing more, just "Cannot convert". Also, this is the full code, so there is nothing else.

```
 function days(){   
      var table = new Array(7); 

      for ( var i = 0; i < 7 ; i ++){
        table[i] = i+2;  
        }

       var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Want");
           sheet.getRange("B2:B9").setValues(table); 

        }
```

Comment: I updated it a little bit, is it better now? Let me know if anything is missing.

Comment: Do you happen to know which line throws the error? What steps are you taking to create/reproduce the error? What steps have you taken to eliminate the error? What has or has not worked for you so far? [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything about Google Apps Scripting, but I managed to find [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_range#setValues) on Google.

It appears your table needs to be a 2-dimensional array.

Perhaps this can help?

(code is from the link above)

```
var myTable = [[1, 2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8]];
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.getRange(1,1,2,4).setValues(myTable);
```

Answer (score 3):

`SetValues()` takes a 2 dimensions array as argument, `TABLE` is a 1 dimension array... this cannot work as it is... It's easy to change though, make table a 2D array of 7 elements.

like this :        `table[i] = [i+2];`

btw,  range ('B2:B9') is 8 cells high and you only give 7 values... there will be a problem there !

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem to this question, so I will answer the question so that others may benefit. The problem here is that the .setValues method for a Range object must be given a two dimensional array [][]. So I created a 0 dimensional array inside of the other one so that i now had a two dimensional array.

```
var array = new Array(7);

 for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    array[i] = new Array(0);
  }
```

Comment: That looks even better than my example!

Comment: If you want that 'other may benefit' please don't leave your code as it is, also don't forget to change range size from 8 to 7 ;-)

Comment: What do you mean by range size. Also just to clarify, I should change the code in my original code so that it is correct?

Comment: B2:B9 is 8 cells high, TABLE has only 7 elements, the code will generate an error .  You can indeed add the new code in an edit in your question.